# Follow Button of Twitter cross-browser

Tags: css, iframe, twitter, cross-browser

I want to add a Follow Button of Twitter on my mean-stack web page. I use the following code:

https://jsbin.com/herikik/3/edit?html,output

```
  <iframe
    src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name=Google&show_screen_name=false&show_count=false&size=l"
    title="Follow us on Twitter"
    width="80"
    height="30"
    style="border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

In Chrome under Mac, it works well. However, in Chrome and Edge under Windows, it shows:

[image]

Does anyone know how to modify the code such that it shows well cross-browser?

Comment: Try adding `scrolling="no"` to the `<iframe>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding `scrolling="no"` to the `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe
    src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name=Google&show_screen_name=false&show_count=false&size=l"
    title="Follow us on Twitter"
    width="80"
    height="30"
    style="border: 0; overflow: hidden;"
    scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```